# How to get facebook page reviews Even i have accessToken

Tags: facebook, facebook-access-token, review

I want to get only facebook page reviews. I have accessToken and I am able to access the feed/post. What permission should I set to get page reviews and what should be complete url to get fb page reviews, which I can use in an API call ?

Please respond it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ratings/

The only thing you need is a Page Token.

How to get a Page Token is explained here:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: Can we get the page access Token using AppAccessToken ?

Comment: how to get a page token is explained in the last 2 links of my answer. you need a user token with at least manage_pages to get a page token.